# How to access an encrypted NTFS partition?

Tags: encryption

I have a partition encrypted with Kaspersky KryptoStorage in Windows XP. I reinstalled Windows XP and am now no longer able to access the partition. How can I mount that NTFS partition and access its data from the Ubuntu 10.10 live CD? I do know the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i fear kaspersky kryptostorage is not compatible with linux and uses an proprietary format.

You have to try with xp  and the original software. In the future i would the opensource + cross platform truecrypt.